# How to Debug an MPI Algorithm in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am testing this algorithm ([Gridpoint Statistical Interpolation](https://dtcenter.org/community-code/gridpoint-statistical-interpolation-gsi/download), which has ended its support) and have been following its [online tutorial](https://dtcenter.org/community-gsiv3-7-online-tutorial/other-practical-cases/case-9-chem-case-gsi-analysis-wrf-chem), specifically case 9. As a sort of summary for the algorithm, it basically tries to estimate a function that has the minimum error from a set of observations, and case 9 takes around two iterations for the function to converge to the observation (it's somehow similar to estimating a best-fit line in machine learning).

Unfortunately, case 9 always results into a segmentation fault. I usually run the algorithm using four processes, and the segmentation fault occurs right after the second iteration ends. However, when I try to use more than, or even less than, four processes, the segmentation fault occurs right after the first iteration.

I have checked where the segmentation fault happens, and it happens, according to the error message, at the if-clause (this is  found in the mpeu_util.F90)

```
do i=1,size(varnames)
 if(trim(usrname)==trim(varnames(i))) then
    getindex_=i
    exit
 endif
enddo
```

I was suspecting that the algorithm somehow tries to extract values outside the permitted range of `varnames`, and have tried to debug it with a simple print but it seems that there's nothing wrong. Is it possible that the thread was released and the algorithm tries to read from this thread, resulting in a segmentation fault? How can I check this?

Edit: The algorithm works for the other cases in the online tutorial.
Edit 2: I double-checked, and the algorithm runs with MPI rather than OpenMP.

Comment: Is (and how) your question OpenMP related?

Comment: I double-checked and the algorithm actually runs with MPI rather than OpenMP, I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: the snippet does not contain any MPI code, please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [paragraph](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#serial-debuggers) on the OpenMPI website on how to debug programs with an example with a C program, easily adaptable to C++, probably adaptable to Fortran.

The idea is to built a "breakpoint" yourself in your code with a while loop going forever on a boolean that you set in the code to `True` and will set to `False` only once you've attach your processes to GDBs instances with `gdb -pid {}` where you get your PID number how you like (a call to a function in Fortran like in the example, or with top/htop on the CLI).

Me, personally, I use VScode to attach to a process and like this I can enjoy the graphic interface of VScode debugger instead of GDB's. For that, I add a configuration "(gdb) Attach" to `.vscode/launch.json`. You can access your `launch.json` from the debug tab in VScode :

[image]

And clicking the wheel :

[image]

And here is what I add to the field `configuration` :

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Attach",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "attach",
    "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    "program": "your/path/to/the/executable/running/on/each/MPIprocess",
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
},
```

After that, and selecting "(gdb) Attach" in the debug tab like in the screenshot, when you hit f5 the command pick process is triggered and you can type the name of your program, it'll show all instances launched by MPI and you can attach to them.

Don't know much about Fortran and about your problem specifically, but with this you should be able to debug and track down where your segmentation faults occurs.

I'll also add that you can get info about memory leak and sometimes seg fault with valgrind, you can look into that in you're interested.